# Enable-PSRemoting: Is there security threats?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, powershell, remote-access

I have two production servers (Windows Server 2008, Terminal Servers) and I would like to enable PowerShell remoting commands on those servers. Is there a security threat one should consider before running

```
Enable-PSRemoting -force
```

on these servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely - but that's true of every remote management method that's ever existed.

Where you're exposing it to and what hosts you're allowing to connect is a big factor in the risk - allowing anyone on the internet to connect is much less safe than a select few hosts on your LAN.  It's also worth bearing in mind that it's a pretty new protocol, and it's bound to have some vulnerabilities discovered at some point.

Whether you should or should not do it is ultimately a decision that needs to be made based on the exact deployment that you're planning and your organization's tolerance for risk; we're not really in a position to make recommendations.